# date range wise fetch data

Tags: php, html, yii2

I have two date filters (`from` and `to`) which will represent days in the current month and I declare them as two variables.

How do I run a `for` loop in each field from `start_date` to `end date`?

I want to fetch the data in the selected date range. The table header is done, it show current selected date.

[image]

Here is my  code:

```
$start_date = date('d', strtotime($from));
$end_date = date('d', strtotime($to));

?>
<div>
<div>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
        <?php
        $dates = range($end_date, $start_date);
        foreach ($dates as $fpi) {
            echo '<th>' . $fpi . '</th>';
        }
    ?>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="text-center">
    <tr>
        <td class="font-weight-bold text-no-wrapping">man</td>
        <?php
        foreach ($data['man'] as $value) {
            echo '<td>' . number_format($value) . '</td>';
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="font-weight-bold text-no-wrapping">women</td>
        <?php
        foreach ($data['women'] as $value) {
            echo '<td>' . number_format($value) . '</td>';
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="font-weight-bold text-no-wrapping">children</td>
        <?php
        foreach ($data['children'] as $value) {
            echo '<td>' . number_format($value) . '</td>';
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="font-weight-bold text-no-wrapping">as</td>
        <?php
        foreach ($data['as'] as $value) {
            echo '<td>' . number_format($value) . '</td>';
        }    
        ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="font-weight-bold text-no-wrapping">ot define</td>
        <?php
        foreach ($data['not_define'] as $value) {
            echo '<td>' . number_format($value) . '</td>';
        }    
        ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="font-weight-bold text-no-wrapping">old</td>
        <?php
        foreach ($data['old'] as $value) {
            echo '<td>' . number_format($value) . '</td>';
        }
        ?>    
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: We don't yet have enough sample data in your [mcve].  We can't see `$data`.

Answer (score 0):

this will loop through the dates range, feel free to change `$date->format('Y-m-d)` to what you need

```
$date = $start_date
while($date <= $end_date){
    echo '<th>' . $date->format("Y-m-d"). '</th>';
    $date->modify('+1 day');
}
```